# gmagick and GraphicsMagicks: static linking

Tags: linux, go, static-linking, cgo, graphicsmagick

I'm trying to compile a binary written in Go that we have a static linking with GraphicsMagick (go gmagick and his libgraphicsmagick1-dev package).

Actually the binary works perfectly in dynamic, but I would like an out-of-the-box, to avoid installing libraries, configurations, etc.

I'm not at all familiar with static linking, here's what I tried:

```
CGO_ENABLED=0
go build --ldflags='-extldflags=-static'
```

and the result was an avalanche of errors (I will mention a few, the output is way bigger than that):

```
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0xd18): undefined reference to `exp'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(libGraphicsMagick_la-gem.o): in function `Hull':
(.text+0x1369): undefined reference to `GOMP_parallel'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x13ad): undefined reference to `GOMP_parallel'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(libGraphicsMagick_la-gem.o): in function `Contrast':
(.text+0x17d3): undefined reference to `sin'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(libGraphicsMagick_la-gem.o): in function `ExpandAffine':
(.text+0x3a8): undefined reference to `sqrt'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(libGraphicsMagick_la-image.o): in function `DisplayImages':
(.text+0x1bde): undefined reference to `XOpenDisplay'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x1bfd): undefined reference to `XSetErrorHandler'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x1cb0): undefined reference to `XCloseDisplay'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(libGraphicsMagick_la-image.o): in function `AnimateImages':
(.text+0x26ca): undefined reference to `XOpenDisplay'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x26e9): undefined reference to `XSetErrorHandler'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x2746): undefined reference to `XCloseDisplay'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(libGraphicsMagick_la-log.o): in function `LogMagickEventList':
(.text+0xbb0): undefined reference to `fmod'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0xf01): undefined reference to `fmod'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(libGraphicsMagick_la-omp_data_view.o): in function `AllocateThreadViewDataSet':
(.text+0xba): undefined reference to `omp_get_max_threads'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(libGraphicsMagick_la-omp_data_view.o): in function `AccessThreadViewData':
(.text+0x2c5): undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(libGraphicsMagick_la-pixel_cache.o): in function `AccessDefaultCacheView':
(.text+0x17ad): undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(libGraphicsMagick_la-pixel_cache.o): in function `AccessImmutableIndexes':
(.text+0x1839): undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(libGraphicsMagick_la-pixel_cache.o): in function `AccessMutableIndexes':
(.text+0x1909): undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(libGraphicsMagick_la-pixel_cache.o): in function `AccessMutablePixels':
(.text+0x19d5): undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(libGraphicsMagick_la-pixel_cache.o):(.text+0x1b76): more undefined references to `omp_get_thread_num' follow
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(libGraphicsMagick_la-pixel_cache.o): in function `AllocateThreadViewSet':
(.text+0x3c25): undefined reference to `omp_get_max_threads'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(libGraphicsMagick_la-pixel_cache.o): in function `GetImagePixelsEx':
(.text+0x5e56): undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(libGraphicsMagick_la-pixel_cache.o): in function `GetImagePixels':
(.text+0x5f6a): undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(libGraphicsMagick_la-pixel_cache.o): in function `SetImagePixels':
(.text+0x617c): undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(libGraphicsMagick_la-pixel_cache.o): in function `SetImagePixelsEx':
(.text+0x622c): undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(libGraphicsMagick_la-pixel_cache.o): in function `SyncImagePixels':
(.text+0x67a8): undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(libGraphicsMagick_la-pixel_cache.o):(.text+0x6838): more undefined references to `omp_get_thread_num' follow
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(libGraphicsMagick_la-pixel_iterator.o): in function `PixelIterateMonoRead._omp_fn.0':
(.text+0x94): undefined reference to `GOMP_loop_nonmonotonic_guided_start'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x184): undefined reference to `GOMP_loop_nonmonotonic_guided_next'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x191): undefined reference to `GOMP_loop_end_nowait'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(libGraphicsMagick_la-pixel_iterator.o): in function `PixelIterateMonoModifyImplementation._omp_fn.0':
(.text+0x2c5): undefined reference to `GOMP_loop_nonmonotonic_guided_start'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x443): undefined reference to `GOMP_loop_nonmonotonic_guided_next'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x450): undefined reference to `GOMP_loop_end_nowait'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(libGraphicsMagick_la-pixel_iterator.o): in function `PixelIterateTripleImplementation':
(.text+0x506): undefined reference to `omp_get_max_threads'
```

and obviously the binary is not created.

It is as if the compiler did not find the C code to compile. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that while you have 'GraphicsMagick' statically compiled , `libGraphicsMagick.a`, you do not have its dependencies compiled statically as:

- `omp_get_max_threads` is from OpenMP
- `XCloseDisplay` I think is from Xlib
- the math functions 'sin' and 'fmod' are coming from another library as well